# VB.net string split get the first value

Tags: vb.net, string

I am working with a string that will always have "Product 1:"
in it. I want to get the value of what comes after "product 1:". Here are some example of the string

> Hello UserName Product 1: Alcatel Product 2: Samsung Truck: Fedex
>   Ending: Canada
>
> Hello UserName Product 1: NOKIA Truck: Fedex Ending: Canada
>
> Hello UserName Product 1: Alcatel Product 2: Samsung Product 3: NOKIA
>   Truck: Canada POST Ending: Brazil
>
> Hello UserName Product 1: Alcatel-55 Special Product 2: Samsung
>   Product 3: NOKIA Truck: Canada POST Ending: Brazil
>
> Hello UserName Product 1: Samsung Galaxy S6-33 Truck: Canada POST
>   Ending: Brazil

The string I am looking for:

- Alcatel
- NOKIA
- Alcatel
- Alcatel-55
- Samsung Galaxy S6-33

I  was having a little bit of luck with

```
sMessage.Split("Product 1:")(1).Split(":")(1)
```

But with above code I still get

- Alcatel
- **NOKIA Truck**
- Alcatel
- Alcatel-55
- **Samsung Galaxy S6-33 Truck**

Comment: What about `sMessage.Split("Product 1:")(1).Split(":")(1).Replace(" Truck", "")`?

Comment: I'd expect "Alcatel Product 2" as a result of your current approach. You could try multiple delimiters like `.Split("Product 2:", "Truck:")` but I guess a real solution would rather require regex.

Comment: You need a definition of where to stop. It looks like you want the text between "Product 1:" and the next tag, i.e. "Truck:" or "Product 2:"... You'll need either a list of the tags, or rules about their construction to use a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the undesired values with:

```
sMessage.Split("Product 1:")(1).Split(":")(1).Replace(" Truck", "")
```

You can also match the desired string with regular expressions:

```
(?<=Product 1: )((.*)(?= Product 2:)|(.*)(?= Truck:))
```

Example:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Product 1: )((.*)(?= Product 2:)|(.*)(?= Truck:))")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("Hello UserName Product 1: NOKIA Truck: Fedex Ending: Canada")
```

Note that if there are more delimiters than `Product x` and `Truck` you want to remove then you need to add those to the regular expression (or replace).

**Edit**

Updated the regular expression to be more generic in regards of delimiter words:

```
(?<=Product 1: )((.*)(?= Product 2:)|(.*?)(?= \w+:)|.*)
```

Now it will match on `Product 2:` or any other, or no delimiter.

**Edit 2**

More simplifications:

```
(?<=Product 1: )((.*?)(?= \w+ ?(\d+)?:)|.*)
```

This last regular expression also matches correctly if there is a delimiter with multiple digits like `Products 123:`.

Comment: REPLACE idea works for my specific case. Thank you. I do intrigue with regex idea but for now I will do the easy REPLACE :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you want the value between "Product 1:" and whatever the next "tag" happens to be, which in some cases is "Product 2:" and in other cases is "Truck:". Keep in mind that this is based only on the sample you provided - if you have other "tags" which can appear after the "Product 1:", you'll need to adjust.

The following regex will get you almost what you asked for

```
(?:Product 1:)(?<product>.+?)(?=(\sProduct 2:)|(\sTruck:))
```

Using that regex, and given your sample text, you will get capture groups named "product" as follows:

- Alcatel
- NOKIA
- Alcatel
- Alcatel-55 Special
- Samsung Galaxy S6-33